# Save XML file in Datagridview with DataTable without adding DataTable.Name to XML File

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, datatable

Language: C#

I want to save a XML file that I have loaded into a DataGridView from a DataTable. I know that in order to use the .WriteXML() I have to give a name to the DataTable. My problem is when I do this the DataTable Name is then used as a wrapper around each of the elements inside of my XML file. I don't want this to happen. I just want to edit the XML file's values and keep it in the same layout.

This is how my code is being put into the DataTable and DataGridView:

```
string pathOfXML = C:\\FIlePath;

DataTable dt = new DataTable("XML_Table");    

public void XML_Document()
{
  XML_FILE = XDocument.Load(pathOfXML);

  dt.Columns.Add("Name");
  dt.Columns.Add("Value");

  var rows = doc.Root.Descendants().Select(element => new
  {
   Name = element.Name,
   Value = element.Value,
  }); 

  rows.ToList().ForEach(i => dt.Rows.Add(i.Name, i.Value));

  dgv_XML.DataSource = dt;
}
```

I then call this method in my FormLoad() so it can populate the DataGridView.

I'm trying to save the XML changes with a button click event, here is the code:

```
 void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
   dt.WriteXML(pathOfXML);

   Messagebox.Show("Save Successful!");
 }
```

The XML file should look like this (It's extremely basic):

```
<Root>
    <Element> Value </Element>
    <Element> Value </Element>
    <Element> Value </Element>
    <Element> Value </Element>
    <Element> Value </Element>
    <Element> Value </Element>
    <Element> Value </Element>
</Root>
```

This is what it looks like whenever I try to save it:

```
<Root>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
    <XML_Table>
       <Name> Element Name </Name>
       <Value> Element Value </Value>
    </XML_Table>
</Root>
```

This edits the values and saves them, but it puts the "XML_Table" around every element, I just want to stop that "XML_Table" from happening.

Comment: DataTable dt is defined twice.  Move to public space outside both methods so you are using the same instance of 'dt'.

Comment: @jdweng Good eye, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Show us the XML you want.

Comment: Edited my original post to show the layout of XML and how the XML is being saved.

Comment: That is the way the DataTable Write.Xml() method works.  if you want a different format you have to write your own code to save file and to read file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating dynamic labels to hold the Elements and textboxes to hold the Values. Then I created a for loop so that I could get the incremental "i". I then placed a foreach loop inside of the for loop so that I could iterate through each element and replace the values in those elements with the values that the array now holds.

```
int lblpositionX = 17;
int lblpositionY = 39;
int increment = 0;
string[] arr1 = {};

foreach (XElement Name in XDocumentName.Root.Descendants())
{
   Label lbl = new Label();
   lbl.Text = Name.ToString();
   lbl.Name = Name.ToString();
   lbl.Location = new Point(lblpositionX, lblpositionY);
   lblpositionY += 25;

   TextBox txt = new TextBox();
   txt.Text = Name.Value.ToString();
   txt.Name = "XML_Text" + increment;
   txt.Location = new Point(txtpositionX, txtpositionY);
   txtpositionY += 25;

   pnl_XML.Controls.Add(lbl);
   pnl_XML.Controls.Add(txt);
}

private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var textboxes = pnl_XML.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(Control => Control.Text);
   arr1 = textboxes.ToArray();
   int textBox = textboxes.Count();

   for (int i = 0; i < textBox; i++)
   {
      foreach (XElement Name in XDocumentName.Descendants())
      {
         Name.Value = arr[i];
         i++
      }
      XDocumentName.Save(pathofXML);
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use `DataTable.WriteXml` and `DataTable.ReadXml` methods for writing and reading respectively.

What is your ultimate goal?

If you want to reduce the file size, then set the column mapping to attributes instead of elements. Also specify the short name for the table.

```
var dt = new DataTable("dt"); // short table name

// mapping to attribute
dt.Columns.Add("Name").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
dt.Columns.Add("Value").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;

dt.Rows.Add("name1", "value1");
dt.Rows.Add("name2", "value2");

dt.WriteXml("test.xml");
```

This will produce the following result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <dt Name="name1" Value="value1" />
  <dt Name="name2" Value="value2" />
</DocumentElement>
```

As you can see, the result is very compact. And pretty much in line with what you want.

---

Well, try the complete example code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        path = "test.xml";

        dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        buttonLoad = new Button { Parent = this, Top = 170, Text = "Load" };
        buttonSave = new Button { Parent = this, Top = 200, Text = "Save" };

        buttonLoad.Click += ButtonLoad_Click;
        buttonSave.Click += ButtonSave_Click;
    }

    DataGridView dataGridView;
    Button buttonSave;
    Button buttonLoad;

    string path;
    DataTable dataTable;
    DataSet dataSet;

    private void ButtonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataSet = new DataSet("Root");

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            dataSet.ReadXml(path, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
            dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
        else
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable("dt");

            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Value").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;

            dataTable.Rows.Add("name1", "value1");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("name2", "value2");

            dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
        }
        dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    }

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataSet != null)
            dataSet.WriteXml(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned in answer to use the DataTable.ReadXml, but you didn't use it in your actual answer, did you forget? I tried using it and it did not load into my DataGridView correctly. The columnMapping works great and puts my edited XML correctly, but it still adds the DataTable's name to the rows. I need that left out so that I can load the XML file into my DataGridView correctly if it needs to be edited again. When the saved file is loaded into the DataGridView, it only shows the DataTable Name in the "Name" column and nothing else.

Comment: @AnthonyScheel - _left out_ - For what? What is your **ultimate** goal? Why you create a wrong xml format, and then heroically trying to read it?

Comment: This is the format that I've been given. If I could get my team to change the format then I would. My **ultimate** goal is to load this file into a datagridview or some other format, then edit the XML, then save the XML back into the same file with the updated values. The XML format that I posted at the top is what I need, if I can't accomplish this with a DataGridView and DataTable then I'll have to find another way of going about this. Your updated answer only displays the first element and value in the first row and nothing else.